# Riemann’s Rearrangement Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a question regarding to th Riemann’s Rearrangement Theorem:
I want to prove that if $\sum a_n$ is conditionally convergent then there exist a series with the same terms but with different order that converge to $\infty$.
Now, I know that if a series $\sum a_n$ is conditionally convergent then there must be infinity positive terms and infinity negative terms. Is that correct to define a series that the first terms are the infinity positive terms and then the series converge to $\infty$?. If so, is there any formal proof for this?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can't do that; the order of addition must follow the ordering of $\mathbb{N}$. Try to see if you can use the definition of conditional convergence (as opposed to conventionally convergent alternating series) to your advantage.